# Gulp. Compile all .jade files when child (_*.jade) included

Tags: javascript, gulp, pug, gulp-watch

I have next structure:

```
jade
├── _skeleton.jade
├── _header.jade
├── _footer.jade
|
├── includes
│ └── _include-on-index.jade
│ └── _include-on-page-1.jade
│ └── _include-on-all-pages.jade
|
├── pages
│ └── index.jade
│ └── page-1.jade
│ └── page-2.jade
│ └── page-3.jade
```

And I need to setup jade compile, like some apps, (for example Prepros).

It means that if I edit page-3.jade I need compile only page-3.jade, if I edit file that start with _*.jade, I don`t need compile exectly this _*.jade file like html, but I need to compile all .jade files that included this _*.jade file

For example when I edit file _header.jade, I need compile all files that included _header.jade, if I edit _include-on-index.jade I need to compile file without _ that included _include-on-index.jade

I`m trying to do this with module [gulp-jade-find-affected](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jade-find-affected), but it works incorrect, and it compile files that start with _*.jade as html.

Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    jade = require('gulp-jade'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    affected = require('gulp-jade-find-affected');

gulp.task('watch-jade', function () {
  '!sources/jade/_*.jade'
  watch('sources/jade/*.jade')
      .pipe(affected())
      .pipe(jade())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('site'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch-jade']);
```

Maybe someone have this gulp task and can help me ?